# Typedef usage not clear

Tags: c, list

I am learning C and i am not clear about `typedef`. I am creating a Linked List.

**type.h**

```
#ifndef

struct Node;
typedef struct Node *PtrToNode;
typedef PtrToNode List;
typedef PtrToNode Position;

List MakeEmpty( List L);
int IsEmpty( List L);
int Islast( Position P, List L);
Position Find( ElementType X, List L );
void delete( ElementType X, List L );
Position FindPrevious( ElementType X, List L );
void Insert( ElementType X, List L, Position P );
ElementType Retrieve( Position P );
#endif
```

I have a doubt `ElementType` is not created with `typedef` but how can we use this declaration.

**type.c**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "type.h"

struct Node
{
    ElementType Element;
    Position Next;
};
```

Is the declaration of `ElementType` in `Struct Node` is valid or not. if yes, How ?

Comment: This code compiles without errors?

Comment: Where is `ElementType` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Prototypes in **type.h** use only a pointer to `struct Node` not the struct itself. Therefore it's not necessary that the type Node is complete when you include the file type.h.

But you have to define all elements with the types of the elements before you can *use* or *implement* and of the function that have been decleared in **type.h**. For the use of the function you need to instantiate objects what's impossible with incomplete types. The implementation will typically dereference the pointer what's also impossible with incomplete types.

Therefore you must define the typedef `ElementType` before using any instance of `struct Node`.